# How do I sort my HashMap keys - they are not sorting?

Tags: java

I have a

```
HashMap<String, Integer>.
```

I want to extract all the keys, ie Strings into an String array. Then, I want to sort this String array and use it.

Unfortunately, the String array is not sorting and producing the output I want.

**Current output is -**

```
one, 
two, 
zero,
```

**Output needed is -**

```
zero, 
one, 
two,
```

**The code is given below -**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;


public class HashMapKeySorter {

    public static String[] convert(HashMap<String, Integer> codes){

        Set set = codes.keySet();
        Object[] object = set.toArray();
        String[] allKeys = new String[object.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < object.length; i++){
            allKeys[i] = (String) object[i];

        }

        Arrays.sort(allKeys);
        return allKeys;

    }


    public static void main(String[]args){

         HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

         hm.put("zero", 0);

         hm.put("one", 1);

         hm.put("two", 2);

         String[] allKeys = convert(hm);
         showStringArray(allKeys);

    }


    public static void showStringArray(String[] allKeys){

        for(int i = 0; i < allKeys.length; i++){

            System.out.println(allKeys[i] + ", ");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: So, you want the program to sort your `String`s according to english numbers?

Comment: Every alphabet I've ever seen puts "z" after "o" and "t".

Comment: Your code works like a charm, sorting the keys *alphabetically* ([link to a demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/wsbszJ)).

Comment: @HotLicks You don't have to venture very far: the *alphabet* itself (in the narrow sense!) sorts Zeta before almost everything else :)

Comment: You have to write a custom Comparator, but I think you are going to have bigger problems such as when you get into things as forty-five or sixty-two.

Comment: The keys are being sorted lexicographically as strings.  If you want to sort them as numbers, then you need to parse the word into a number and then sort by that.

Comment: From the example, there are two possible interpretations, sort by English word meaning or sort by value in the Map. The latter is the more reasonable, and could be done using a comparator that looks its arguments up in the Map and calculates its result from the values.

Comment: Looks like you want to be sorting on the values that are in your map, ie the integer equivalents of the strings

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Well, programming is all Greek to me anyway.

Comment: Okay, that was one hell of a dumb error. Should i stop programming ? :(

Comment: SO can seem unforgiving. Don't take it personally!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are approaching it wrong. What you want is:

1) Get the `entrySet()` from the `Map`.

2) Sort the entries by their `value`

3) Print the `key` of each sorted entry

What your program does is sort the `key`s alphabetically. And it does it fine.

Comment: In fact I can't tell if it is alphabetically or just by character code. Are collation rules applied by default on `String`s?

Comment: Collations can be applied by a so called `Collator` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html. In german it is pretty bad if you want 'ä' after 'a', in this case you use the collator for your locale. Java's `String#compareTo` itself would sort on the character code, so 'ä' would follow long time after 'z'

Comment: Okay, that was one hell of a dumb error. Should i stop programming ? :(

Comment: @david blaine Nah, it just takes a bit more than 23 hours  :P

Answer (score 5):

You need a custom comparator:

```
Arrays.sort(allKeys, new Comparator<String>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2)
    {
        // the implementation of the comparator
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay, that was one hell of a dumb error. Should i stop programming ? :(

Answer (score 4):

Replace your call to `Arrays.sort(array)` with Arrays.sort(array,[Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29))

You will have to write your own custom comparator that sorts 'zero' before 'one'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort not by the lexicographic value (which is what you are currently sorting on), then you will need to make a custom comparator that will sort by the Numeric value of the String (like "one" == 1).

Java doesn't have something like this built in, so you will need to do a bit of coding, easist will be a switch on the string that returns the numeric number.